# IoT applications with heavy-load wireless communications

Tags: smart-home, wireless, industry-4.0, mobile-applications, smart-cars

I am very interested in the examples of IoT applications where a heavy-load (for large amounts of data) wireless communications have to be used.

To the best of my knowledge, most IoT devices would not require too large bandwidth. The things I've found on IoT SE:

- [Industrial IoT, high-density](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/3342/suitable-wireless-technologies-for-high-density-industrial-iot) - I would not qualify ~1 Mbps as high, also I am interested in a bit more details on what kind of information has to be sent this way.
- [MQTT](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/3026/mqtt-always-connected-and-4g-data-load) without a particular application.

I am certainly interested in ideas/sources for personal/industry applications in all the *smart* areas.

Answer (score 4):

Your best source of consumer IoT that use/generate large amounts of data is most likely going to be Camera/streaming video devices.

Advances in on device motion/person detection mean that even these sort thing are more likely to only stream video when events are detected or the use explicitly requests to watch the stream.

Answer (score 2):

I'm familiar with a product which records information such as direction, speed (RPM), and torque on a device which operates at a high rate of speed. We aggregate data during normal operation, but if an error occurs during operation we send a very large file with pretty much all data for the session.

Another product sends data a low rates during normal operation, but when we're adjusting performance reporting is increased by about 500% to ensure quick reaction if the adjustment doesn't produce the expected results.

Comment: That’s very interesting! Any references/links I can take a look at?

Comment: Unfortunately these are proprietary applications which is why my descriptions were so vague.. If we do make any part of the architecture public I will post a link.